# How to sort a 2d array using the second index for tiebreaks

Tags: java, lambda, expression

Anyone know the correct syntax for sorting an 2d array using Lambdas in java where in the need to tiebreak we move on to the second element?
like if the array is { {1,0}, {2,5}, {1,55}}
it becomes {{1,0}, {1,55}, {2,5}}

So Im familair that the syntax for just sorting the array as input follows the syntax of

````
     ```java
         Arrays.sort(input, (a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0));
      ```
````

I have tried some of my own experimental ways around this, such as

````
```java
 Arrays.sort(input, (a,b) ->
  int c1 = a[0];
  int c2 = b[0];
if(c1 == c2) return a[1] - b[1];
   return c1 - c2;
);
````

but these still have syntax errors in various places. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need braces around the lambda body when it consists of more than one expression. Also, `Integer.compare` should be preferred over subtracting (consider overflow).

```java
Arrays.sort(input, (a, b) -> {
    int c1 = a[0];
    int c2 = b[0];
    if (c1 == c2) return Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]);
    return Integer.compare(c1, c2);
});
```

This can be simplified with `Comparator` methods.

```
Arrays.sort(input, Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(x -> x[0]).thenComparingInt(x -> x[1]));
```

[`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) generalizes this lexicographic order for arrays of any length (as mentioned by [Eritrean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5176992)).

```java
Arrays.sort(input, Arrays::compare);
```